# Faster minimization of $$\|I-x A B - x B A + x^2 A B A\|^2_F$$

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

Are there any tricks I can use to speed up minimization of the function below for positive definite matrices $A,B$ and scalar $x$?

$$f(x)=\|I-x A B - x B A + x^2 A B A\|^2_F$$

This is a bottleneck in my code, orders of magnitude slower than calling `SingularValueDecomposition`, wondering if there's an approach  which works much faster.

```
frob2[mat_] := With[{vec = Flatten[mat]}, Total[vec vec]];
makePosdef[mat_] := mat . mat\[Transpose];
d = 40;
a = makePosdef@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {d, d}];
b = makePosdef@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {d, d}];
ii = IdentityMatrix[d];
obj[x_] := frob2[ii - x a . b - x b . a + x^2 a . b . a];
Minimize[obj[x], x] // Timing (* {1.811757, ... *)
```

Comment: With the definition `frob2[mat_] := Expand[Total[mat^2, 2]];` the execution is quite a bit faster. `Expand` turns the expression into a straightforward polynomial in `x`, which is easy to minimize.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The objective function is a polynomial of order 4 in `x`. Writing out its coefficients once, we can minimize it by finding its critical points and then taking the one with the smallest function value:

```
ab = a . b;
ba = b . a;
aba = ab . a;
c[0] = d;
c[1] = -4 Tr[ab];
c[2] = 2 Tr[aba + ab . ab + ab . ba];
c[3] = -4 Tr[ab . aba];
c[4] = Tr[aba . aba];
f[x_] = c[0] + c[1] x + c[2] x^2 + c[3] x^3 + c[4] x^4;
criticalpoints = x /. Solve[f'[x] == 0, x];
xmin = MinimalBy[Select[criticalpoints, Developer`MachineRealQ], f][[1]]
```

On my machine this takes less than a millisecond for `d = 40`.

Comment: I'd suggest solving only in $\mathbb{R}$: `criticalpoints = SolveValues[f'[x] == 0, x, Reals]` and then `xmin = MinimalBy[criticalpoints, f]`.

Comment: Thanks for these pointers! =) For performance reasons, I'd rather stick to finding the critical points in $\mathbb{C}$ and filter the real solutions with ``Developer`MachineRealQ``. (I hope that `Solve` is clever enough to correctly idenify real solutions and to represent them by `Real`s, not by `Complex`s. That should be easy for polynomials of degree 3...)

Comment: I'm wondering if I could use Mathematica to just get the formula I can plug in. There's reason to believe that this objective is convex, so there should be a unique real root

Comment: related follow-up here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/273310/simplifying-formula-for-a-real-valued-root-of-the-quartic